# Bytecode instrumentation generating java verifier error

Tags: java, assembly, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM in order to do bytecode instrumentation for Java programs.  What I'm doing is simple - When instrumenting a method, if the instruction is a PUTFIELD, simply do a DUP_X1 right before the instruction, then visit the PUTFIELD and inject a function call with an argument that includes the DUP'ed stack entry.

```
                public void visitFieldInsn(
                                int opcode,
                                String owner,  // owner of this field...
                                String name,
                                String desc) {

                    boolean did_dup = false;

                    if(opcode == Opcodes.PUTFIELD) {
                        if(!owner.equals("java/lang/System")) {
                            if (desc.startsWith("L")) {
                                mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP_X1);                                       
                                did_dup = true;
                            }
                        }

                    } 

                    mv.visitFieldInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);

                    if (did_dup) {
                        mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
                        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/amir/ASide", "updateG", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V");
                    }

                 }
```

The code looks like this BEFORE and AFTER instrumentation, respectively :

```
public void setA(ClassA classa)
{
    refA = classa;
    eyeColor = classa.eyeColor;
}


public void setA(ClassA classa)
{
    ASide.updateG(refA = classa, this);
    ASide.updateG(eyeColor = classa.eyeColor, this);
}
```

But when I run the instrumented code, I get :

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting to find object/array on stack

Can you offer has any help on this?

Comment: Are you sure it's complaining about the modified setA method?

Comment: It's not complaining about the setA method Martin - thats a keen observation.  Do you think that I should look into the actual method that it's complaining about?  It appears to be related to inner classes.

Comment: This has something to do with inner classes - but I"m not sure why that should matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some holes in your instrumentation. For instance, it doesn't check if you are inside static method, so this variable is present.

Comment: Solved along time ago but you are correct.  And of course you are correct, you are the author of ASM!!!  Thanks again, I'm a huge fan